# How to color-highlight specific "keywords" in multiPageEditor eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have made a multiPageEditor Eclipse Plugin and it is properly working. The contents of file are properly displayed in this editor.

Now here, I want to highlight specific keywords when the file is displayed in the editor.

`How shall I implement this functionality ?`

I have researched about this but not able to find anything appropriate. Even other related questions are not what I want.

I found the concept of `Presentation Reconciler` but it seems to be very vast. I don't need that deep functionality, I just want to highlight specific keywords when the file is being displayed in the text editor.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but the presentation reconciler is the way this is normally done. Possibly using Eclipse xText or similar might help.

Comment: greg-449 : I was expecting you. :) Thanks for the quick reply. 
If "Presentation Reconciler is the only workaround, then can you please help me with that itself.